# BufferedReader.readLine() blocks for a while

Tags: java, android, tcp, bufferedreader

I am trying to get a String of http response (just a JSON object), and sometimes this piece of code waits infinite time in

> `line = reader.readLine()`

May be, the reason of such behavior is bad Internet connection (I use 3G modem), but I need a stable solution to avoid this infinite lock. What can be done here to avoid it?

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

InputStream content = null;
JSONObject json_obj;
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    try {
        content = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8"), 256);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: You could do the `readLine()` stuff in a separate thread and close the reader when you want to kill everything

Comment: why (and most importantly how) would you consider avoid network queries to be non-blocking? (also, EntityUtils.toString does what you do in 1 line)

Comment: @fiddler I already do this in background thread, the question was only about blocking.

Comment: @njzk2 Also about blocking. The problem was that blocking occurred when request was already sent to the server and server responded, but response was never received and not received completely and thread was waiting for nothing. So timeout is good thing, just didn't know how to set it.

Comment: the thing is, there is no way of knowing if you are waiting because your connection is crappy or because the request was lost in the first place. So yes, timeouts can be adjusted to best fit your use cases, but htey are still necesary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a read timeout:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 30000);
```

Should set a read timeout to 30 seconds.
Probably, you also want to specify a connection timeout:

```
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
readLine()
```

Or any network/IO should be done in a background thread to prevent locking of the main thread.

If you test your code on Android 4.0+ you'll also see that networking is no longer allowed on the main thread and will throw an exception.

Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is a simple, painless way of running such tasks on a background thread.

Comment: I already do this in background thread, the question was only about blocking.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution to avoid the "infinite" lock is to do this http calls in a separate thread, and with a Handler, notice to the main thread that the info is loaded and can use it like you want.

Here an example of my own using a SaxParser too:

```
public void SearchFromSuperClass(String text)
{   
    mHandler = new Handler();
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
              String strurl="URLTOPATH";
              URL url = new  URL(strurl);
              SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

              SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
              FundsHandlerRanking handler = new FundsHandlerRanking();
              parser.parse(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), handler);
              search_response = handler.getrankings();


              mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                search_response = null;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

            }

        }
    };

    t.start();
}
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateResultsInUi();
    }
};

private void updateResultsInUi() {

    try
    {
        if(search_response != null)
        {
            lview.setAdapter(new SearchRankingAdapter(mycontext, search_response, false));
        }
        Pdialog.dismiss();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        lview.setAdapter(null);
        if (Pdialog.isShowing())
        {
            Pdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

With mHandler.post(...) you put the call in the queue to be sended to the main UI thread, and there, you can modify UI objects without problem (CAN'T modify UI objects outside the Main thread).

Hope this helps

Comment: There is a good option put a timeout as a http call parameter